# C# linq DefaultIfEmpty() NullReferenceException Value cannot be empty. Parameter name: Source

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem
How can I inquire in a linq correctly
Get a mistake NullReferenceException every time

```
    public class Model
    {
        public int Nmb { get; set; }
        public string _UserId { get; set; }
    }
    public static List<Model> _models_List { get; set; }

        string user = "test name";

        int test = _models_List.Where(o => o._UserId == user).Select(o => o.Nmb).DefaultIfEmpty(0).First();

        if (test == 0)
        {         
            Model obj = new Model();
            obj._UserId = user;
            obj.Nmb = 1;
            _models_List.Add(obj);
        }
```

I tried to correct the code like this
But I get the same mistake
NullReferenceException
Value cannot be empty. Parameter name: Source

```
    int test = _models_List.Where(o => o._UserId == user).Select(o => o.Nmb).FirstOrDefault();
```

Please Help

Comment: `string _UserId = _models_List.Where(o => o._UserId == user).Select(o => o._UserId).FirstOrDefault();`, can be replaced with `var userExists = _models_List.Any(o => o._UserId == user);`

Comment: [edit] your question and include a [mcve]. You could provide test data for `_models_List`

Comment: Thanks for your response, sir
you are right
But I just want to know how to inquire the correct in linq, so I attached this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list `_models_List` is empty, to solve the issue replace the following code:

```
public static List<Model> _models_List { get; set; }
```

with:

```
public static List<Model> _models_List { get; set; } = new List<Model>();
```